# Count collections on database mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

How can I know how many collections exists in a database in mongoDB in mongoshell (mongosh)

The only thing I have is `db.getCollectionNames()` but I can't count the lenght ot that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can use `db.getCollectionNames().length`

Comment: Hahahhahaha I had a typo in length, so I thought the method didn't exist xd. Thanks a lot